ERROR URI when calling SOAP API with WSDL on NEXT JS
const soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
const path = require('path');
import type { CollectPaymentRequest } from './CollectPaymentRequest';
import type { CollectPaymentResponse } from './CollectPaymentResponse';
import type { GetPaymentRequest } from './GetPaymentRequest';
import type { GetPaymentResponse } from './GetPaymentResponse';

// Define the WSDL URLs
const WSDL_QA_URL = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/app/xx/wsdl/qa.wsdl');
const WSDL_PROD_URL = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/app/xx/wsdl/prod.wsdl');

console.log('WSDL_QA_URL:', WSDL_QA_URL);
console.log('WSDL_PROD_URL:', WSDL_PROD_URL);

export const createClient = async (
  mode: string,
  keys: { username: string; password: string },
): Promise<any> => {
  const wsdl = mode === 'qa' ? WSDL_QA_URL : WSDL_PROD_URL;

  if (!wsdl) {
    throw new Error(`WSDL URL is not defined for mode: ${mode}`);
  }

  const options = {
    wsdl_headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(
        `${keys.username}:${keys.password}`,
      ).toString('base64')}`,
    },
    endpoint: wsdl,
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    soap.createClient(wsdl, options, (err: any, client: any) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(`Failed to create SOAP client: ${err.message}`));
      } else {
        console.log('Client description:', client.describe());
        // Check the available services and ports
        const services = client.wsdl.definitions.services;
        console.log('Available services:', Object.keys(services));
        for (const service in services) {
          const ports = services[service].ports;
          console.log(
            `Available ports for service ${service}:`,
            Object.keys(ports),
          );
        }
        resolve(client);
      }
    });
  });
};

export const collectPayment = async (
  request: CollectPaymentRequest,
  client: any,
): Promise<CollectPaymentResponse> => {
  console.log('Calling collectPayment with request:', request);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const availableMethods = client.describe();
    console.log('Available methods on client:', availableMethods);

    if (!client.collectPayment) {
      reject(
        new Error(`collectPayment method is not available on the client.`),
      );
      return;
    }

    client.collectPayment(
      { arg0: request },
      (err: any, result: CollectPaymentResponse) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error(`Failed to collect payment: ${err.message}`));
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      },
    );
  });
};

export const getPayment = async (
  request: GetPaymentRequest,
  client: any,
): Promise<GetPaymentResponse> => {
  console.log('Calling getPayment with request:', request);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!client.getPayment) {
      reject(new Error(`getPayment method is not available on the client.`));
      return;
    }

    client.getPayment({ arg0: request }, (err: any, result: any) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(`Failed to get payment: ${err.message}`));
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};

I am trying to call a SOAP API with WSDL file on NEXT JS application but getting this error
"Error: Error: Failed to collect payment: Invalid URI"
Verified that the paths resolved by path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/app/xx/wsdl/qa.wsdl') and path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/app/xx/wsdl/prod.wsdl') are accurate.
